# Munin Interpretation - Server Limits

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze, munin, graph

I've installed Munin to monitor my debian (squeeze) webserver (2 x Intel Quad Xeon 4x2.66GHz, 16GB RAM, 2x1000GB HDD Raid). There are around 50k visits per day.

The scripts are very simple and there is a caching system with files to avoid too much mysql-requests. There are a lot of image requests. CPU is 99% idle.

I don't know if there are still enough resources to serve 100k visits per day or if I have to do something (e.g. change to nginx).

I added four images of munin which I think have the highest information value.

*original URL: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/cx4.png/*

[image: ss #1]

*original URL: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/g2d1.png/*

[image: ss #2]

*original URL: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images//547/7w4h.png/*

[image: ss #3]

*original URL: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/qd7.png/*

[image: ss #4]

What I've done already:

- KeepAlive 2s (increased the memory load)
- Cachetime min. 1 week
- Compression is enabled

Is there room for more visits or are the server limits reached?

Comment: Could you show "Load average" ?

Comment: What you can read from the memory-graph is that you are constantly overcommitting memory. This seems to correlate with the traffic to your server. This is not necessarily bad, because you still have a lot of memory free, but you should be aware that something (Apache probably) is committing more memory than you have.